# printing array data using forlopp

Tags: php, arrays

```
$responses= stdClass Object (
 [status] => SUCCESS
 [value] => stdClass Object (
   [messageTaskList] => Array (
     [0] => stdClass Object (
       [id] => 19
       [userId] => 38
       [text] => some text
       [currentCount] => 0
       [finishCount] => 5000
       [createTime] => 1470223038000
       [finishTime] =>
       [status] => 1
       [requestsSent] => 0
       [url] => linked.in/searchparams=marketingits=sample )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
       [id] => 20
       [userId] => 38
       [text] => Grand Rapids
       [currentCount] => 0
       [finishCount] => 5000
       [createTime] => 1470223059000
       [finishTime] =>
       [status] => 1
       [requestsSent] => 0
       [url] => linked.in/searchparams=marketingits=sample )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
       [id] => 21
       [userId] => 38
       [text] => Grand Rapids
       [currentCount] => 0
       [finishCount] => 5000
       [createTime] => 1470223751000
       [finishTime] =>
       [status] => 1
       [requestsSent] => 0
       [url] => https://google.com ) ) )
 [action] => GET_MESSAGE_TASK_LIST
 [eventId] => )

foreach($responses as $key => $value) {
                    echo $value->id . ", " . $value->text . "<br>";
                }
```

I am trying to show the array value in the table but I am getting the error mentioned below.

> **Notice**: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\linkedin\all-tasks.php on line 238
>
> **Notice**: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\linkedin\all-tasks.php on line 238

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` and `text` is within the array objects of `value` and `messageTaskList`, so by putting pointers on the same, loops enters into the inner array where `id` and `text` resides.

This should be helpful:

```
foreach($responses->value->messageTaskList as $key => $value) {

      echo $value->id . ", " . $value->text . "<br>";

}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: "id" and "text" is within the array objects of "value" and "messageTaskList", so by putting pointers on the same, loops enters into the inner array where "id" and "text" resides.

Comment: I understood.. Thank You for the help

Comment: Great, I added that to your answer, which is where you should have put it. So now it is definitely worth an upvote, so I gave you one. Good answers get you upvotes(+10) as well as an accepted answer(+15)

Answer (score 1):

This is how Your $responses structure looks like:

```
$responses = stdClass (
    [status] => SUCCESS
    [value] =>
        stdClass Object (
            [messageTaskList] => Array (
                [0] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 19
                    [userId] => 38
                    [text] => some text
                    [currentCount] => 0
                    [finishCount] => 5000
                    [createTime] => 1470223038000
                    [finishTime] =>
                    [status] => 1
                    [requestsSent] => 0
                    [url] => linked.in/searchparams=marketingits=sample
                )
                [1] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 20
                    [userId] => 38
                    [text] => Grand Rapids
                    [currentCount] => 0
                    [finishCount] => 5000
                    [createTime] => 1470223059000
                    [finishTime] =>
                    [status] => 1
                    [requestsSent] => 0
                    [url] => linked.in/searchparams=marketingits=sample
                )
                [2] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 21
                    [userId] => 38
                    [text] => Grand Rapids
                    [currentCount] => 0
                    [finishCount] => 5000
                    [createTime] => 1470223751000
                    [finishTime] =>
                    [status] => 1
                    [requestsSent] => 0
                    [url] => https://google.com
                )
            )
        )
        [action] => GET_MESSAGE_TASK_LIST
        [eventId] =>
    )
```

All You need to do is to iterate on the right element:

```
foreach ($responses->value->messageTaskList as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->id . ", " . $value->text . "<br>";        
}
```